# Why does ListHeader in phone:LongListSelector moves during scrolling?

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have the following Windows Phone 8 XAML markup:

```
<phone:LongListSelector 
    x:Name="PeopleListSelector" 
    ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
        <phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
            <TextBlock Text="People" Style="{StaticResource PhoneTextExtraLargeStyle}"></TextBlock>
        </phone:LongListSelector.ListHeader>
        ...
</phone:LongListSelector>
```

When I scroll the list, my header scrolls along with the list. Is it expected behavior?

Not sure if that is relevant, but I have a StackPanel and two phone:LongListSelector controls inside a grid

Answer (score 1):

Which other kind of behaviour did you expect?

To answers your question: yes, it is normal.